# How to get the width of a div's inner content using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a div with a bunch of images inside floated left. I want to get the collective width of all the images. I know I can just grab the width of the div since it expands to fit it's contents but how can I do it the other way, by calculating the inner content's width?

### EDIT

Sorry here's the markup:

```
   <div id="gallery">

        <ul>
           <li><img src="images/a.png" /></li>
           <li><img src="images/b.png" /></li>
           <li><img src="images/c.png" /></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
```

I need to get the width of all the lis combined.

Comment: We need to see some markup; please can you add the relevant code into your question.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
var totalWidth = 0;
$('#gallery li').each(function(){
    totalWidth  += $(this).outerWidth(true);
});
```

`totalWidth` will give you the combined `width` of all the li's inside the `div#gallery`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not so sure about this because I haven't done many tests on it.
There are two attributes, [scrollWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollWidth) and [scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollHeight) which return "the width/height in pixels of the content of an element or the width/height of the element itself, whichever is greater".

This is vanilla JS but you can use it with jQuery too like this:

`var totalWidth = $('#gallery').get(0).scrollWidth;`

It worked for me. But I haven't tested much.

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this:

```
    var sumWidth = 0;
    $('selector').each(function(){
        var sumWidth += $(this).width();
    });
    alert('the width sum is: '+sumWidth);
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -2):

There is the [innerWidth()](http://api.jquery.com/innerWidth/) function.  We will need to see your HTML to advise further.

Comment: `innerWidth()` takes padding into account. `width()` uses the actual content width. Then again, the initial question was about the actual width of the content, not looking at the element size itself.